# Flutter 2: Best practice using/store the size of the phone

Tags: flutter

I am trying to find a best practice for using some casual data.

For example, I have seen in some videos ([*for example this one*](https://youtu.be/LN668OAUrK4)), people storing their size at the beginning of their page and sending it as a parameter for every stateless widget they have.

`Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;`

[image]

Is it better for the performances (*even if it's a really little*) to do like this or is it better to access it every time via `MediaQuery.of(context).size` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

calling `MediaQuery.of(context)` is in order of `n` where `n` is the length of your widget tree. so it's not that bad for most cases. also using `MediaQuery.of(context)` and not passing along constructors makes your code cleaner. but your widgets should not depend on the size of the screen. in most cases widgets like `Flex`, `Expanded`, `FitedBox` and .. can help you achieve this.

Comment: Ok, it was what I was thinking of, but was scared to miss some optimization tricks.

Answer (score 1):

the `LayoutBuilder` widget could be an alternative. It passes the constraint that belongs to the parent widget, rebuilds if the constraints change. I think it is a cooler solution :D

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html